# Unable to order by columns without including the column names in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am unable to order by query without including the column names in group by. Trying to update the latest record with next latest not null values. But when i am updating the record random not null values are considered instead of next latest not null values as order by cannot be performed unless included in group by.

Table A

```
  ID     Name   zip  city  Mdate
  10001  Sarah  NULL NULL  02-20-2018 00:10:40:000
  98765  AJ     NULL Asia  03-25-2018 10:10:45:000
  12345  NULL   7511 Texas 03-20-2018 22:10:00:000
```

Table B

```
  ID     RollNo     Cdate
  12345   1    01-18-2018
  12345   2    01-22-2018
  12345   3    03-20-2018 
  98765   9    01-18-2018
  98765   8    01-22-2018
  98765   7    03-20-2018
  10001   10   03-08-2018 
  10001   11   01-15-2018
  10001   12   02-20-2018
```

TABLE C

```
  Rollno Name  Zip  City  Mdate
    1    NULL  7511 Texas 01-18-2018 15:10:00:000 
    2    John  5001 NULL 01-22-2018 10:05:00:000
    3    NULL  7000 Rome 03-20-2018 22:10:00:000
    10   Sarah NULL NULL 03-08-2018 01:00:20:000
    11   Tom   5500 NULL 01-15-2018 15:10:00:000
    12   NULL  4500 Pune 02-20-2018 00:10:40:000
    9    AJ    NULL Asia 01-18-2018 23:01:02:000
    8    MATT  NULL Ohio 01-22-2018 20:00:05:000
    7    NULL  8000 NULL 03-25-2018 10:10:45:000
```

Query:

```
    Update #temp SET Name = C.name
    Zip = C.ZIP
    ,City=C.city

   FROM
   (
   SELECT A.ID,
   CASE 
   WHEN MAX(A.Name) IS NULL THEN MAX(C.Name) 
   ELSE Max(A.Name) 
   END Name,
   CASE
   WHEN MAX(A.Zip) IS NULL THEN Max(C.Zip)
   ELSE MAX(A.Zip)
   END Zip,
   CASE 
   WHEN MAX(A.City) IS NULL THEN Max(C.City) 
   ELSE MAX(A.City) 
   END City,
   A.Mdate
   FROM table_a A
   INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
   INNER JOIN table_c C ON B.RollNo = C.RollNo
   GROUP BY A.ID,A.Mdate
   )
```

Result set:

```
   ID     Name   zip  city  Mdate
  10001  Sarah  5500 Pune  03-08-2018 01:00:20:000
  98765  AJ     8000 Asia  03-25-2018 10:10:45:000 
  12345  John   7511 Rome  03-20-2018 22:10:00:000
```

Actual output:

```
   ID     Name   zip  city  Mdate
  10001  Sarah  4500 Pune  03-08-2018 01:00:20:000
  98765  MATT   8000 ohio  03-25-2018 10:10:45:000 
  12345  John   7000 Rome  03-20-2018 22:10:00:000
```

If the latest records are holding null values then next latest not null value records should be updated. In the query unable to provide orderby for table C mdate. I have taken latest values into temp table and performing update to only specific columns.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  `ORDER BY` in a subquery is generally not useful.

Comment: For sub queries if you need a preference in the ordering use select top, that way you can rank the data based on the presence of null values

Comment: @GordonLinoff i need to update the null with not null values from table C as per the latest modified date. Where as my query is updating not null values but randomly.hope you got it

Comment: @DwightReynoldson can you give an example based on my query i tried many ways but couldnt get the output.

Comment: Your ordering of the data and your stated desired output don't match up. Take a look just at ID 10001. The name would be Tom based on the most recent NON-NULL value. But you state it should be Sarah. Same issue with zip. it would be 4500 based on dates but you say it should be 5500. The real issue here is you seem to be pulling certain values from various rows. This is huge red flag that your design is less than ideal.

Comment: Or...maybe you are assuming that a table has an inherent order and you want the ordering to be based on the order of rows in the table. That will never work because by definition are unordered sets. You need some value to use for ordering. My guess this is exactly what you mean. Without a column to order by you are trying an impossible task.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about ordering within a sub query, this doesn't produce the result set you are looking for (your original query also doesn't produce the actual output from the data set provided) but this is the method I would use to solve the problem.

```
create table #temp (id int, name char(5), zip char(5), city char(5));

       declare @table_a table (id int, name char(5), city char(5), zip char(5), mdate datetime);

       insert @table_a
       values(10001,  'Sarah',  NULL, NULL,  '02-20-2018 00:10:40:000'),
       (98765,  'AJ',     NULL, 'Asia',  '03-25-2018 10:10:45:000'),
       (12345,  NULL,   7511, 'Texas', '03-20-2018 22:10:00:000');

       declare @table_b table (id int, rollno int, Cdate datetime);

       insert @table_b ( ID,     RollNo,     Cdate)
       values
  (12345,   1,    '01-18-2018'),
  (12345,   2,    '01-22-2018'),
  (12345,   3,    '03-20-2018'),
  (98765,   9,    '01-18-2018'),
  (98765,   8,    '01-22-2018'),
  (98765,   7,    '03-20-2018'),
  (10001,   10,   '03-08-2018'), 
  (10001,   11,   '01-15-2018'),
  (10001,   12,   '02-20-2018');

       declare @table_c table ( rollno int, name char(5), city char(5), zip char(5),mdate datetime);

       insert @table_c(  Rollno, Name,  Zip,  City,  Mdate)
       values
    (1,    NULL,  7511, 'Texas', '01-18-2018 15:10:00:000'), 
    (2,    'John',  5001, NULL, '01-22-2018 10:05:00:000'),
    (3,    NULL,  7000, 'Rome', '03-20-2018 22:10:00:000'),
    (10,   'Sarah', NULL, NULL, '03-08-2018 01:00:20:000'),
    (11,   'Tom',   5500, NULL, '01-15-2018 15:10:00:000'),
    (12,   NULL,  4500, 'Pune', '02-20-2018 00:10:40:000'),
    (9,    'AJ',    NULL, 'Asia', '01-18-2018 23:01:02:000'),
    (8,    'MATT',  NULL, 'Ohio', '01-22-2018 20:00:05:000'),
    (7,    NULL,  8000, NULL, '03-25-2018 10:10:45:000');

       declare @count int = coalesce((select count(*) from #temp), 100);

    --Update t SET t.Name = C.name,
    --t.Zip = C.ZIP,
    --t.City=C.city

select * 
   FROM
   (
   SELECT top (@count) A.ID,
   CASE 
   WHEN MAX(A.Name) IS NULL THEN MAX(C.Name) 
   ELSE Max(A.Name) 
   END Name,
   CASE
   WHEN MAX(A.Zip) IS NULL THEN Max(C.Zip)
   ELSE MAX(A.Zip)
   END Zip,
   CASE 
   WHEN MAX(A.City) IS NULL THEN Max(C.City) 
   ELSE MAX(A.City) 
   END City,
   A.Mdate
   FROM @table_a A
   INNER JOIN @Table_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
   INNER JOIN @table_c C ON B.RollNo = C.RollNo
   GROUP BY A.ID,A.Mdate
   order by A.Mdate
   ) C 


   drop table #temp;
```

If you need to order on the Mdate within the C derived table I'd use a variable built from a count of the number of rows that you want to update within the #temp table to populate a top statement within your sub-query. That way you can control the ordering.